# Logback dependency preventing SBT running offline

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy, logback

This is a refinement of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014492/sbt-0-13-1-offline) with closer attribution to the problem.

I'm trying to confirm I can run my SBT project offline.  I can, unless logback is one of my libraryDependencies.  Why is logback triggering a problem?  I've made a simple example consisting of just a build.sbt and a 'hello world' app...

**build.sbt** with a bunch of random dependencies to prove the point:

```
name := "testProject"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.2",
    "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.4.0.1",
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.1",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.1", 
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.3.1",
    "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.3"
)
```

My steps

1. Delete `~/.ivy2`, `~/.sbt`, and `target/` inside my project, just to be sure
2. Ensure connected to the internet, and do `sbt run`.  My hello world runs successfully
3. Disconnect from internet
4. `sbt clean`
5. `sbt run`.  Build fails with logback as an unresolved dependency
6. Remove the logback dependency and `sbt run` again.  Hello world runs.

This is the error from step 5:

```
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1 ...
[warn] Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/logback-classic-1.1.1.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[warn]  module not found: ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/user/.ivy2/local/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/logback-classic-1.1.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1: not found
```

**Update:**

Using the `last` command in SBT there is a *lot* of debug info for dependency resolution.  Here's an example of Akka resolving successfully:

```
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1 ...
[debug] sbt-chain: Checking cache for: dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1 {compile=[default(compile)]}
[debug] sbt-chain: module revision found in cache: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1
[debug]     local: revision in cache: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1
[debug]     found com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1 in sbt-chain
[debug] == resolving dependencies testproject#testproject_2.10;0.0.1->com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1 [compile->runtime]
[debug] == resolving dependencies testproject#testproject_2.10;0.0.1->com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1 [compile->compile]
[debug] == resolving dependencies com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1->org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3 [compile->master(*)]
[debug] == resolving dependencies com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1->org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3 [compile->compile(*)]
[debug] == resolving dependencies com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.1->com.typesafe#config;1.2.0 [compile->master(*)]
```

Here's the failure for Logback:

```
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1 ...
[debug] sbt-chain: Checking cache for: dependency: ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1 {compile=[default(compile)]}
[debug]         tried /home/user/.ivy2/local/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[debug]     local: no ivy file found for ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1
[debug]         tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/logback-classic-1.1.1.pom
[warn] Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/logback-classic-1.1.1.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[debug]     public: no ivy file found for ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1
[warn]  module not found: ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/user/.ivy2/local/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/logback-classic-1.1.1.pom
```

I can confirm the following files in the cache (not the '~/.ivy/local' folder):

```
~/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic$ ls
ivy-1.1.1.xml  ivy-1.1.1.xml.original  ivydata-1.1.1.properties  jars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try it, the file is indeed resolved from ~/.ivy2/cache.  I have no ~/.ivy2/local because I do not publish locally.  Is it possible that you have an ivysettings.xml file (on Linux, try `locate ivysettings.xml`) that is messing with some [Ivy cache attribute](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/caches.html), like resolutionCacheDir?  It would still be a mystery why you only have problems with that one jar....

UPDATE: This appears to be a regression in SBT 0.13.1; it worked in 0.13.0, and as the OP himself discovered (see his answer), it was fixed in 0.13.2.

Comment: Also, if you weren't the one who posted this to the sbt alias, you might want to chime in and follow it:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/wHHxpVrxLfU

Comment: I couldn’t find an ivysettings file, but just to be sure I built a fresh VM (CrunchBang) and copied only the jdk, sbt, build.sbt, and the .scala application file.  I got the same result.  It’s still failing to find only logback-classic, and no such ‘local’ dir exists.  Presume you cleaned before trying to run again when offline?

Comment: Yes, I did sbt clean (which removes the target directory but does not touch ~/.ivy2) after disconnecting, before sbt run.  It all worked fine for me with the very build.sbt you provided (and a trivial scala program that just echoes its args).

Comment: Are you using SBT version 0.13.1?

Comment: I'm using 0.13.0.  Looks like this was a regression in 0.13.1?

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: @Pengin, was it still somehow related to Logback? I have never ever been able to use sbt offline, not in any version. And I have always used logback in every project I guess. The setOffline := true simply doesn't work since it seems to retrieve the deps before. SNAPSHOT dependencies are unresolved even though I have them in my .ivy/cache

Comment: @hedefalk It wasn’t to do with Logback, but a problem with SBT 0.13.1.  I have a feeling that using ‘SNAPSHOT’ means that it will always try to resolve to get the latest version, which isn’t what you want when offline.  I guess you need to put in specific versions of dependencies.  Then you should be able to build on a PC that’s on the internet, then go offline/copy over .ivy2 & .sbt.  That’s what I do and it seems to work reliably now.

Comment: @Pengin Thanks, yeah I figured. To me this is way too broken. I need to be able to work offline sometimes, but have NEVER been able to do so reliably with SBT.

Answer (score 1):

It can't find it in your local ivy cache, fix that and you've solved your problem.

Try clearing out your ivy cache, maybe it's corrupt.

Comment: That's what I thought, so have deleted the entire '.ivy2' and '.sbt' folders several times, and still run into the same problem on all PCs.

Comment: I'm not an ivy expert, can you enable debug mode to see what's it's doing?

Answer (score 0):

SBT 0.13.2 was released 3 days after this question, and seems to resolve the problem.  I don't know if this was a known issue, but the changes listed for SBT 0.13.2 include

> Fix issue where ivy's .+ dependency ranges were not correctly
>   translated to maven.